# Getting AngularJS orderBy to sort both directions

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm attempting to setup a clickable table column header that sort Ascending when first clicked, and Descending when clicked again. My ascending sort is working fine, but I'm not sure how to setup an expression within my OrderBy to sort Descending

My setup thus far:

Table html has something like

```
<th ng-click="sort('LastName')">Last Name</th>
```

My sort method looks like

```
scope.sort = function (columnName) {
    if (angular.isDefined(scope.filter)) {
        if (scope.filter.SortColumn == columnName) {
            scope.filter.SortColumn = columnName;
            scope.filter.SortDirection = scope.filters.SortDirection == "Asc" ? "Desc" : "Asc";
        } else {
            scope.filter.SortColumn = columnName;
            scope.filter.SortDirection = "Asc";
        }
    }
 };
```

And my ng-repeat looks as follows

```
<tbody ng-repeat="name in resp.Names | orderBy : filter.SortColumn">
```

How can I get the SortDirection to factor into the orderBy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To simply reverse you'd change it to this:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="name in resp.Names | orderBy : filter.SortColumn : true">
```

It'd be best if you used a boolean in your controller, but this should work too:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="name in resp.Names | orderBy : filter.SortColumn : filter.SortDirection === 'Desc'">
```

And just for fun, here's how I do sorting with filtering in my tables.

Controller:

```
$scope.search = { query: ''};
$scope.sort = { field: 'defaultField', descending: true};

$scope.order = function(newValue) {
  if(newValue === $scope.sort.field) {
    $scope.sort.descending = !$scope.sort.descending;
  } else {
    $scope.sort = {field: newValue, descending: false};
  }
};

$scope.filteredDocuments = function() {
  var a = $filter('filter')($scope.documents, {$:$scope.search.query});
  var b = $filter('orderBy')(a, $scope.sort.field, $scope.sort.descending);
  return b;
};
```

A search box for filtering:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search.query">
```

A column header:

```
  <th nowrap>
    <a href ng-click="order('size')">Size </a>
    <i ng-show="sort.field === 'size' && !sort.descending" class="fa fa-sort-amount-asc"></i>
    <i ng-show="sort.field === 'size' && sort.descending" class="fa fa-sort-amount-desc"></i>
  </th>
```

The row binding:

```
  <tr ng-repeat="d in filteredDocuments()" >
```

Comment: Bingo. I switched it to a boolean, and now it works flawless. Thanks!

Comment: That's a solid setup.

Answer (score 0):

A simplified version of the above answer:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<p>Click the table headers to change the sorting order:</p>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="namesCtrl">

<table border="1" width="100%">
<tr>
<th ng-click="orderByMe('name')" >Name</th>
<th ng-click="orderByMe('country')">Country</th>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="x in names | orderBy:myOrderBy:mySortOrder">
<td>{{x.name}}</td>
<td>{{x.country}}</td>
</tr>
</table>

</div>

<script>
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('namesCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = [
        {name:'Jani',country:'Norway'},
        {name:'Carl',country:'Sweden'},
        {name:'Margareth',country:'England'},
        {name:'Hege',country:'Norway'},
        {name:'Joe',country:'Denmark'},
        {name:'Gustav',country:'Sweden'},
        {name:'Birgit',country:'Denmark'},
        {name:'Mary',country:'England'},
        {name:'Kai',country:'Norway'}
        ];
    $scope.sorts={};
    $scope.orderByMe = function(x) {
        $scope.myOrderBy = x;
        if(x in $scope.sorts) {
         $scope.sorts[x]=!$scope.sorts[x];
        } else {
         $scope.sorts[x]=false;
        }
        $scope.mySortOrder=$scope.sorts[x];
    }
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```